# SAS: Error Variable was referenced but not given value

Tags: arrays, sas, syntax-error

```
data iris;
input sepal_length sepal_width petal_length petal_width class $ @@;
Datalines;
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.9 3.0 1.4 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.0 3.6 1.4 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4 Iris-setosa
4.6 3.4 1.4 0.3 Iris-setosa
5.0 3.4 1.5 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.4 2.9 1.4 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1 Iris-setosa
5.4 3.7 1.5 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.8 3.4 1.6 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.8 3.0 1.4 0.1 Iris-setosa
4.3 3.0 1.1 0.1 Iris-setosa
5.8 4.0 1.2 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.7 4.4 1.5 0.4 Iris-setosa
5.4 3.9 1.3 0.4 Iris-setosa
5.1 3.5 1.4 0.3 Iris-setosa
5.7 3.8 1.7 0.3 Iris-setosa
5.1 3.8 1.5 0.3 Iris-setosa
5.4 3.4 1.7 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.1 3.7 1.5 0.4 Iris-setosa
4.6 3.6 1.0 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.1 3.3 1.7 0.5 Iris-setosa
4.8 3.4 1.9 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.0 3.0 1.6 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.0 3.4 1.6 0.4 Iris-setosa
5.2 3.5 1.5 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.2 3.4 1.4 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.7 3.2 1.6 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.8 3.1 1.6 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.4 3.4 1.5 0.4 Iris-setosa
5.2 4.1 1.5 0.1 Iris-setosa
5.5 4.2 1.4 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1 Iris-setosa
5.0 3.2 1.2 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.5 3.5 1.3 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1 Iris-setosa
4.4 3.0 1.3 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.1 3.4 1.5 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.0 3.5 1.3 0.3 Iris-setosa
4.5 2.3 1.3 0.3 Iris-setosa
4.4 3.2 1.3 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.0 3.5 1.6 0.6 Iris-setosa
5.1 3.8 1.9 0.4 Iris-setosa
4.8 3.0 1.4 0.3 Iris-setosa
5.1 3.8 1.6 0.2 Iris-setosa
4.6 3.2 1.4 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.3 3.7 1.5 0.2 Iris-setosa
5.0 3.3 1.4 0.2 Iris-setosa
7.0 3.2 4.7 1.4 Iris-versicolor
6.4 3.2 4.5 1.5 Iris-versicolor
6.9 3.1 4.9 1.5 Iris-versicolor
5.5 2.3 4.0 1.3 Iris-versicolor
6.5 2.8 4.6 1.5 Iris-versicolor
5.7 2.8 4.5 1.3 Iris-versicolor
6.3 3.3 4.7 1.6 Iris-versicolor
4.9 2.4 3.3 1.0 Iris-versicolor
6.6 2.9 4.6 1.3 Iris-versicolor
5.2 2.7 3.9 1.4 Iris-versicolor
5.0 2.0 3.5 1.0 Iris-versicolor
5.9 3.0 4.2 1.5 Iris-versicolor
6.0 2.2 4.0 1.0 Iris-versicolor
6.1 2.9 4.7 1.4 Iris-versicolor
5.6 2.9 3.6 1.3 Iris-versicolor
6.7 3.1 4.4 1.4 Iris-versicolor
5.6 3.0 4.5 1.5 Iris-versicolor
5.8 2.7 4.1 1.0 Iris-versicolor
6.2 2.2 4.5 1.5 Iris-versicolor
5.6 2.5 3.9 1.1 Iris-versicolor
5.9 3.2 4.8 1.8 Iris-versicolor
6.1 2.8 4.0 1.3 Iris-versicolor
6.3 2.5 4.9 1.5 Iris-versicolor
6.1 2.8 4.7 1.2 Iris-versicolor
6.4 2.9 4.3 1.3 Iris-versicolor
6.6 3.0 4.4 1.4 Iris-versicolor
6.8 2.8 4.8 1.4 Iris-versicolor
6.7 3.0 5.0 1.7 Iris-versicolor
6.0 2.9 4.5 1.5 Iris-versicolor
5.7 2.6 3.5 1.0 Iris-versicolor
5.5 2.4 3.8 1.1 Iris-versicolor
5.5 2.4 3.7 1.0 Iris-versicolor
5.8 2.7 3.9 1.2 Iris-versicolor
6.0 2.7 5.1 1.6 Iris-versicolor
5.4 3.0 4.5 1.5 Iris-versicolor
;
run;



/* Prior predictive checks */
PROC MCMC DATA = iris;
NMC = 5000; /* Size of the sample */
NBI = 0; /* No need to generate burn-in samples, because the draws are taken
directly from the prior */

ARRAY mu[3];
ARRAY sigma[3,3];
PARMS beta1 beta2 beta3 beta4;
PARMS mu;
PARMS sigma;

/* Hyperprior constants */
ARRAY mu0[3] (0 0 0);
ARRAY sigma0[3,3] (625, 200, 200, 200, 625, 200, 200, 200, 625);
ARRAY S[3,3] (500, 50, 50, 50, 500, 50, 50, 50, 500);
/* Prior distributions */
PRIOR beta: ~ NORM(0, var = 10000); /* Note that since the prior distributions for
beta1,beta2,beta3 and beta4 are independent, they can be programmed without a multivariate
distribution. */
PRIOR sigma ~ IWISH(5, S);
PRIOR mu ~ MVN(mu0, sigma0);
/* Constant likelihood function */
MODEL GENERAL(0);
RUN;



PROC MCMC DATA = iris;
NMC = 5000; NBI =0;thin=10;
INIT = RANDOM; /* Random initial values allow Gelman-Rubin diagnostics */

ARRAY mu[3];
ARRAY sigma[3,3];
PARMS beta1 beta2 beta3 beta4 mu sigma ; /* Since this model uses conjugate sampling, the
parameters can all be included in the same PARMS statement without being proposed
together. */
/* Hyperprior constants */
ARRAY mu0[3] (0 0 0);
ARRAY sigma0[3,3] (625, 200, 200, 200, 625, 200, 200, 200, 625);
ARRAY S[3,3] (500, 50, 50, 50, 500, 50, 50, 50, 500);
/* Prior distributions */
PRIOR beta :~ NORM(0, VAR = 10000);
PRIOR sigma ~ IWISH(5, S);
PRIOR mu ~ MVN(mu0, sigma0);
/* Data */
ARRAY class[3] setosa versicolor virginica;
ARRAY sepal_length[3] sepal_length_setosa sepal_length_versicolor sepal_length_virginica;
ARRAY sepal_width[3] sepal_width_setosa sepal_width_versicolor sepal_width_virginica;
ARRAY petal_length[3] petal_length_setosa petal_length_versicolor petal_length_virginica;
ARRAY petal_width[3] petal_width_setosa petal_width_versicolor petal_width_virginica;
ARRAY p[3]; /* Vector of probabilities */
ARRAY exp_eta[4]; /* Vector of linear predictor */
ARRAY alpha[3]; /* Random effects */
/* Sampling model */
RANDOM alpha ~ MVN(mu, sigma) SUBJECT = class MONITOR = (alpha);
/* Calculate exponentiated linear predictor */
DO j = 1 TO 4;
 exp_eta[j] = exp(alpha[j] + beta1 * sepal_length[j] + beta2 * sepal_width[j] + beta3 * petal_length[j] + beta4 * petal_width[j]);
END;
/* Calculate the denominator by summing over exp_eta. */
denom = exp_eta[1] + exp_eta[2] + exp_eta[3] + exp_eta[4];
/* Convert to probabilities */
DO j = 1 TO 4;
 p[j] = exp_eta[j]/denom;
END;
model class ~ MULTINOM(p);
RUN;
```

That's my code, but I keep getting the error:

> ERROR: The variable RANDOM was referenced but not given a value.  
>   ERROR: The variable sepal_length was referenced but not given a value.
>   ERROR: The variable sepal_width was referenced but not given a value. 
>   ERROR: The variable petal_length was referenced but not given a value.
>   ERROR: The variable petal_width was referenced but not given a value.

What do I do to fix it?

Comment: What is it that you want it to do?

Comment: I just want to get rid of those error messages, I don't know why I keep getting them

Comment: This is not in a language that I know, but the errors look like you are creating variables, but not setting them. http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/modules/vars.htm shows something like yours, but it's really not my cup of thee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as though you're referring to arrays and variables with the same names within the same proc. I'm not familiar with `proc mcmc` but if you try and do that in a data step that causes similar errors.

Try renaming your arrays and see if the problems persist.

Comment: Could you by any chance specify what you mean by renaming my arrays? like could you please give me an example? are you just wanting me to change the variable names?

Comment: Where you have e.g. `ARRAY sepal_length...` and you also have a variable in your input dataset called `sepal_length`, try changing the array statement to create an array with a different name, and update the references to that array elsewhere in your code.